# Documentation for Python3 deepcopy's memo and nil parameters incomplete and/or circular?

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone have either (a) an explanation of *copy.deepcopy()*'s *memo* and *nil* parameters, or (b) pointers to genuinely informative documentation about them?

I'm using Python 3.4.1 in the Pydev 3.7.1 console to experiment with *copy.deepcopy*. In the PyDev console, the code completion feature informs me that deepcopy's syntaxt is *deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[])*. I was already making use of *x*, but *memo* and *nil* are new to me.

Here's where I've so far looked for information about those two parameters:

- The Python 3.4.1 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy. That gives me only *copy.deepcopy(x)* -- no *memo* or *nil*.
- In the PyDev Console, *>>> help(copy)*. That gives me *deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[])
  Deep copy operation on arbitrary Python objects. See the module's __ doc __ string for more info.* So I next looked in...
- *D:\Python34\lib\copy.py*'s doc string. The docstring refers me to the docstring. Sigh...
- In *copy.py*'s 333 lines of code. I confess that I'm not at the point where reading the code is informative.
- Searches both here in StackOverflow and on the Web. I managed to find some generic information about the concept of memoization (it's evidently a way to retain the results of an operation so that the operation need not be performed from scratch at its next invocation). I also found some information for Python 2.4 that stated, "Params memo and nil are used in recursive deepcopy,
  their default values are None and empty list". (http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/PQRC-2.4-A4-latest.pdf, inter alia)

The cited 2.4 cheat sheet leads me to guess that the *memo* and *nil* might be used to limit how deeply deepcopy will recurse into a source element's nested sub-elements. But that's only a guess.

So I'm still looking for something that actually explains how to make use of the parameters.

(And should I be thinking about filing a documentation bug insofar as the Python docs system contains an incomplete explanation?)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From lower down in the `deepcopy` documentation:

> Two problems often exist with deep copy operations that don’t exist
>   with shallow copy operations:
>
> - Recursive objects (compound objects that, directly or indirectly, contain a reference to themselves) may cause a recursive loop.
> - Because deep copy copies everything it may copy too much, e.g., administrative data structures that should be shared even between
>     copies.
>
> The deepcopy() function avoids these problems by:
>
> - **keeping a “memo” dictionary of objects already copied during the current copying pass**; and
> - letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set of components copied.
>
> ...
>
> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. **If the `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the `deepcopy()` function with the component as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.**

So that's what `memo` is for. It keeps track of things that got copied already.

`_nil` is an implementation detail. It's used once, as a sentinel value for a `memo.get` call. The fact that it's a default argument is a microoptimization, and the minor time savings of making it a default argument probably don't outweigh the minor confusion from seeing it in the signature.

Comment: So the "in order for a class to define its own copy implementation" bit makes it sound like it's unnecessary to specify "memo" if one is simply using copy.deepcopy(x) to make a deep copy of, say, a list(?) But on the other hand one has created a class that leverages copy.deepcopy(), then that class should specify memo as a way of ensuring that deepcopy will be well behaved? And "nil" is essentially superfluous for human coders?

Comment: @RBV: Depends on what the hypothetical class is doing. If it needs to ensure that copies of overlapping objects use the same copies of the overlapping bits, it needs the `memo` argument. If it needs to ensure the opposite, it shouldn't provide `memo`. `_nil` is completely ignorable, though.